String unshuffler returning different results on windows and linux
I'm working on a project that requires shuffling a string then unshuffling said string later.
Currently I shuffle the string on a Linux machine and attempt to unshuffle on a Windows machine, originally I tested unshuffling on Linux and it returned fine, but when I tried the same code on Windows it returned something completely different and incorrect.
Here is the function that shuffles.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <numeric>

std::string shuffleString(const std::string& str, unsigned int seed) {
    std::string shuffled = str;
    std::vector<int> indices(str.size());
    std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0); // Fill indices with 0, 1, ..., n-1
    std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        shuffled[i] = str[indices[i]];
    }

    return shuffled;
}

Here is the function that unshuffles (it is identical across both Windows and Linux)
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <numeric> 
#include <algorithm>

std::string unshuffleString(const std::string& shuffled, unsigned int seed) {
    std::string unshuffled(shuffled.size(), ' ');
    std::vector<int> indices(shuffled.size());
    std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0); // Fill indices with 0, 1, ..., n-1

    std::mt19937 rng(seed);
    std::shuffle(indices.begin(), indices.end(), rng);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < shuffled.size(); ++i) {
        unshuffled[indices[i]] = shuffled[i];
    }

    return unshuffled;
}


I was going to make a comment about how you should avoid default_random_engine in favour of a specific random engine so you don't get surprises, but I think that might make the question obsolete. How sure are you that default_random_engine is mt19937?
On my Windows box using bog-standard GCC from MSYS2, default_random_engine appears to be minstd_rand0 which in turn appears to be std::linear_congruential_engine<std::uint_fast32_t, 16807, 0, 2147483647> and NOT mt19937
At any rate the sequences generated for
    unsigned int seed = 123456789;
    auto str = shuffleString("hello", seed);
    unshuffleString(str, seed);

on my PC are 1 2 0 3 4 and 2 1 0 3 4. Definitely not the same.
Solution: Make absolutely certain both sides use the same RNG engine. That would probably be mt19937
Note that this still may not hold as the while the engine is being specified, the distribution used by std::shuffle is implementation defined and cannot be manually specified. This isn't a problem if both sides use the same library implementation, but shuffle on Linux, unshuffle on Windows makes it very possible that they are not the same.
If you are forced to overcome this with your own shuffle, The Fisher-Yates Shuffle is a good starting point.

You may want to note that std::shuffle has the same issue, in that how it gets its distribution is implementation defined.

@NathanOliver Didn't think of that. Definitely a problem given the asker's "Scramble on Linux, Unscramble on Windows" requirement.

I apologize lol I was messing around with just random stuff I found online and forgot to change it back to mt19937 before making the post, although I get the same result with std::mt19937 and std::default_random_engine, works fine on linux (unshuffling a string shuffled on linux) but just doesn't for windows. I have confirmed that both use mt19937 or default_random_engine when I was testing with that.

std::default_random_engine is implementation defined. It is not guaranteed to be any of the other std PRNG, nor is it guaranteed to or not to be CSPRNG. It's just a PRNG.

@WhiteKSI That I haven't been able to reproduce. Recommendation: construct a [mre] MRE, a simple program that calls both functions and see if can reproduce. If you can't, it may be a problem with how you're passing the string from program A to program B. Once you've gathered a bit more information with the MRE ask a new question, it's too late to fundamentally change this one, make it clear that you're using the same engine on both sides to reduce the odds of someone not reading closely enough and closing as a duplicate of this question.

Also include in the question the compiler and version and if you're using a Standard Library implementation that isn't the default. If you're using two compilers, make that very clear as it's probably the problem.
